# How to improve this Java Binary search method to find the best percentile for a given value?

Tags: java, search, binary-search, percentile

I have a sorted array of percentile values of home prices baes on X transactions:

`Double[] arr = {2418.0, 2535.0, 2652.0, 2808.0, 2808.0, 2808.0, 2808.0, 2808.0, 2808.0, 3657.0, 3816.0, 4144.0, 5429.0, 5429.0, 5429.0, 5429.0, 5429.0, 5518.0, 5518.0, 5518.0, 5518.0, 5518.0, 5607.0, 5607.0, 5607.0, 5607.0, 5607.0, 5607.0, 5696.0, 5696.0, 5696.0, 5696.0, 5696.0, 5785.0, 5785.0, 5785.0, 5785.0, 5785.0, 5874.0, 5874.0, 5874.0, 5874.0, 5874.0, 5874.0, 5963.0, 5963.0, 5963.0, 5963.0, 5963.0, 5963.0, 6052.0, 6052.0, 6052.0, 6052.0, 6052.0, 6052.0, 6141.0, 6141.0, 6141.0, 6141.0, 6141.0, 6141.0, 6230.0, 6230.0, 6230.0, 6230.0, 6230.0, 6319.0, 6319.0, 6319.0, 6319.0, 6319.0, 6408.0, 6408.0, 6408.0, 6497.0, 6497.0, 6497.0, 6586.0, 6586.0, 6645.4, 6675.0, 6764.0, 6853.0, 6942.0, 7120.0, 7337.3, 7924.2, 8244.5, 8564.0, 8840.0, 9062.2, 9285.9, 9492.1, 9717.5, 10013.2, 10668.4, 12034.5, 13386.0, 22868.0};`

So the 1st percentile of home prices is 2418 and the 100th percentile of home prices is 22868. As with percentiles, based on the input, some percentiles may hold the same values (as `6141`, `6408` and others in the above example).

Now I'm writing a method, that given a home price (not necessarily in the original X transactions), it will find the best percentile it belongs to. I wrote this binary search code that seems to work OK, but I feel it can be improved:

`

```
public static int findRelevantPercentile(Double [] arr, double searchFor){   
    int start = 0;
    int end  = arr.length - 1;
    int middle;
    do{
        middle = (start + end) / 2;
        if (arr[middle] >= searchFor){
            end = middle;
        } else {
            start = middle;
        }
    }while(start + 1 < end);

    if (searchFor >= arr[end]){
        return arr.length;
    } else{
        return start + 1;
    }
}
```

`

If the value that we are looking for is below the 1st percentile it should also be the 1st percentile.
If the value that we are looking for is above the 100th percentile it should also be the 100th percentile.

BTW - I'm aware of Arrays.binarysearch(..) method.

Comment: Are you familiar with `NavigableSet`/`NavigableMap`?

Comment: @JacobG. I'm looking for the percentile, not the value, so I'm not sure navigableMap/set will help here

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @riorio You’d map each array element to its percentile using a `NavigableMap`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple thing that I see that can be improved quickly is moving the If block that is at the end to the beginning so that it never goes into the loop in those specific cases making it slightly faster.

Here is what it would look like after.

EDIT:  I cleaned it up a bit more by changing the DO WHILE to a WHILE and moving the middle declaration to inside the loop since its scope never leaves the loop.

```
public static int findRelevantPercentile(Double [] arr, double searchFor){   
    int start = 0;
    int end  = arr.length - 1;

    if (searchFor >= arr[end]){
        return arr.length;
    }
    while(start + 1 < end) {
        int middle = (start + end) / 2;
        if (arr[middle] >= searchFor){
            end = middle;
        } else {
            start = middle;
        }
    }
    return start + 1;
}
```